# How to consume basic-authentication protected Restful web service via REACTIVE feign client

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-feign

```
@ReactiveFeignClient(name = "service.b",configuration = CustomConfiguration.class)
public interface FeingConfiguration {

    @PostMapping("/api/students/special")
    public Flux<Student> getAllStudents(@RequestBody Flux<SubjectStudent> lista);

}
```

Help, how can I add a basic authentication to my header that I have in the service: service.b.
I have the CustomConfiguration.class class but it doesn't allow me, I have 401 authorization failed

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basic() {
        return  new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("user","user") ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use feign-reactive (https://github.com/Playtika/feign-reactive) to implement your REST clients. I am also using it for one of my projects and it looks like this library does not have an out-of-the-box way to specify basic auth credentials. At least no way to do this declaratively. So I didn't find a better way to do this than to abandon the auto-configuration via @ReactiveFeignClient and start configuring reactive feign clients manually. This way you can manually add "Authorization" header to all outgoing requests. So, provided this client definition:

```
public interface FeingClient {

    @PostMapping("/api/students/special")
    public Flux<Student> getAllStudents(@RequestBody Flux<SubjectStudent> lista);

}
```

Add the following configuration class to your Spring context, replacing username, password and service-url with your own data:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    FeignClient feignClient() {
        WebReactiveFeign
            .<FeignClient>builder()
            .addRequestInterceptor(request -> {
                request.headers().put(
                    "Authorization", 
                     Collections.singletonList(
                        "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( 
                            "username:password".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))));
                return request;
            })
            .target(FeignClient.class, "service-url");
    }
}
```

Note, that this API for manual configurftion of reactive feign clients can differ between different versions of the reactive-feign library. Also note that this approach has a major drawback - if you start creating beans for your feign clients manually you lose the main advantage of Feign - ability to write REST-clients declaratively with just a few lines of code. E.g. if you want to use the above client with some sort of client-side load-balancing mechanism, like Ribbon/Eureka or Ribbon/Kubernetes, you will also need to configure that manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a direct interceptor:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class FeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun reactiveHttpRequestInterceptor(): ReactiveHttpRequestInterceptor {
        return ReactiveHttpRequestInterceptor { request: ReactiveHttpRequest ->
            request.headers()["Authorization"] = //insert data from SecurityContextHolder;
            Mono.just(request)
        }
    }
}
```