# My microservice is not receiving "Authorization" from request header when i use feign-reactive to call it from another microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-feign-client

I have 2 microservices, **ProductStore** and **InvoiceStore**.

I want **ProductStore** to provide product information through an `API` and **InvoiceStore** to call `that API` to get product information from **ProductStore**.
But **ProductStore** needs `Authorization` information to check `user authentication` so I use `@RequestHeader("Authorization") String auth` as argument variable in my `FeignAPI` to send it to **ProductStore**.
But it reported that he did not receive the `Authorization` data when i test it.

I use `@RequestHeader` like that because I see it in the examples of [feign-reactive all feature](https://github.com/Playtika/feign-reactive/blob/develop/feign-reactor-test/feign-reactor-spring-mvc-test/src/test/java/reactivefeign/spring/mvc/allfeatures/AllFeaturesMvc.java)

I don't know if I did something wrong somewhere or I misunderstood the usage of `@RequestHeader`.

Help me please! Here is my code.

My **ProductStore** provides API to be able to get product information.

```
    @GetMapping("products")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization) {
        log.debug("Authorization is {}", authorization);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("all products");
    }
```

And my **InvoiceStore** call that API with `feign-reactive` WebReactiveFeign.

I followed the instructions in the readme of [Playtika feign-reactive](https://github.com/Playtika/feign-reactive) and applied it to my project as follows

First, I write FeignAPI

```
@Headers({ "Accept: application/json" })
public interface FeignClientAPI {

    @RequestLine("GET /products")
    Mono<String> getProducts(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization);
}
```

And then, I build the client in `IvoiceService`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class InvoiceService {
    private final FeignClientAPI client = WebReactiveFeign.<FeignClientAPI>builder().target(FeignClientAPI.class, "http://localhost:8082");

    public Mono<String> testFeign(String authorization){
        log.debug("Call api with authorization: {}", authorization);
        return client.getTest(authorization);
    }
}
```

And then, I create an API

```
    @GetMapping("/invoice/test")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getProducts(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization) {
        return invoiceService.testFeign(authorization)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)))
            .map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(response));
    }
```

Finally, I shoot an `GET` request to `localhost:8083/invoice/test` and I got an error

```
{
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "[400 Bad Request] during [GET] to [http://localhost:8082/products] [FeignClientAPI#getTest(String)]: [{\n  \"title\" : \"Bad Request\",\n  \"status\" : 400,\n  \"detail\" : \"Required request header 'Authorization' for method parameter type String is not present\",\n  \"path\" : \"/products\",\n  \"message\" : \"error.http.400\"\n}]",
    "path": "/invoice/test",
    "message": "error.http.500"
}
```

Tell me where i did wrong, Please!!!
Thank you for everything.

Comment: The InvoiceStore still gets 'Authorization' when i call its API but it doesn't seem to send that data to the ProductStore.

Answer (score 2):

your code is totally wrong and i think you should get compile time error because testFeign(String authorization) need a string input but when you call it ( invoiceService.testFeign().switchIfEmpty ... ) you are not passing any input to it.

i should check the main code ,but i think you are passing null value as authorization in client side ( probably ).

Comment: Oh sorry, I was missing this in the process of turning my code into a simple question to ask. I think I did something wrong in using `feign reactive`. When I enabled anonymous access at `localhost:8083/invoice/test` it worked. You must manually configure `feign reactive` to pass the `authorization header` instead of using the built-in configuration. I managed to do that but it didn't bring any good results for my project. Now I think the problem is with my consul configuration.
Thank you for help.

Comment: I found 1 question about not transmitting authorization here [How to consume basic-authentication protected Restful web service via REACTIVE feign client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609411/how-to-consume-basic-authentication-protected-restful-web-service-via-reactive-f)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.

I misinterpreted how to use `reactive feign` before, which resulted in it not working.

I've added `@EnableReactiveFeignClients` and `@EnableFeignClients` for my spring boot app

```
@EnableReactiveFeignClients
@EnableFeignClients
public class AnswerStoreApp {
// main method
}
```

and then, I create an interface with `@ReactiveFeignClient(name = "my-other-service")`

```
@ReactiveFeignClient(name = "my-other-service")
public interface FeignClientService {

    @GetMapping("/api/questions/test-feign")
    Mono<String> demo(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorize);

    // More request
}
```

finally, I can use `FeignClientService` to get the data that I need

```
@Autowired
private FeignClientService feignClientService;

// Some method

@GetMapping("/invoice/test")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getProducts(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization) {
        return feignClientService.testFeign(authorization)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)))
            .map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(response));
    }
```